# Theme layout not showing on products page

Tags: magento2, layout, theme, xml, frontend

i installed pixtron theme on magento 2, on frontend at products display page the layout of theme is not displaying up properly.

any guidance or help highly appreciated !  ( herewith images attached )
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure you have activated your pixtron theme as current active theme.
You can change theme in Content => Configuration => Edit option
Just activate installed theme.

Go to your root of magento 2 directory and run below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:flush
chmod -R 777 var pub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Remove all files by applying below mentioned command from magento root

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/session/*
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
```

**Note : you are must inside magento root directory.**

Step 2 : Aplly below mentioned command from magento root

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile 
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Now all should be ok.

Comment: If its help please accept as answer